error occured on validate-merchant TypeError: fetch failed SocketError: other side closed UND_ERR_SOCKET nextjs Vercel
error occured on validate-merchant TypeError: fetch failed
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:13178:13
    at async d (/var/task/.next/server/pages/api/validate-merchant.js:1:690)
    at async K (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages-api.runtime.prod.js:20:16853)
    at async U.render (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages-api.runtime.prod.js:20:17492)
    at async r6.runApi (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/server.runtime.prod.js:17:44421)
    at async r6.handleCatchallRenderRequest (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/server.runtime.prod.js:17:38377)
    at async r6.runImpl (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/server.runtime.prod.js:16:17465)
    at async r6.handleRequestImpl (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/server.runtime.prod.js:16:16554)
    at async Server.<anonymous> (/var/task/___next_launcher.cjs:26:5)
    at async Server.<anonymous> (/opt/rust/nodejs.js:8:4429) {
  [cause]: SocketError: other side closed
      at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6020:28)
      at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:531:35)
      at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1696:12)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
    code: 'UND_ERR_SOCKET',
    socket: {
      localAddress: '169.254.100.6',
      localPort: 34978,
      remoteAddress: undefined,
      remotePort: undefined,
      remoteFamily: undefined,
      timeout: undefined,
      bytesWritten: 463,
      bytesRead: 0
    }
  }
}

Here is the error I am getting when merchant validation is happening in apple pay
Here Is the code
const response = await fetch(validationURL, {
 method: 'POST',
 headers: {
   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   },
   body: JSON.stringify({
    merchantIdentifier,
    displayName: 'test',
    initiative: 'web',
    initiativeContext: 'my-verified-domain',
   }),
});

The validation URL I am getting is https://apple-pay-gateway.apple.com/paymentservices/startSession
Please help me figure out the issue
